# Add extra attribute to object Logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Im trying to add an extra attribute to the respons object in logic app.
I got 2 shape that sending request to two different http.
In the third shape i want to merge the body from one respons with the other respons.
Like below

`"ResponsBody":{
  "title": "",
  "created": "",
  "priority": "",
  "Category": "",
  "summary": ""
}`

So want i want take the ID from one of respons and merge it with the other one.

`{
  "ID":""
  "title": "",
  "created": "",
  "priority": "",
  "Category": "",
  "summary": ""
}`

So far this is what i get.
`23123{"title": "","created": "","priority": "","Category": "","summary":""}`
the ID is outside.

Code in Logic app:
 "body": "@{triggerBody()?['ID']}@{body('Get_HTTP_Info')?['data']}"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the @union function to merge two objects

```
"body": "@union(triggerBody(), body('Get_HTTP_Info'))"
```

To add specific properties only, you can first use a compose action to prepare the content

```
"compose1": {
  "type": "compose"
  "inputs": { "id": "@triggerBody()['Id']"}
}
```

And then you can do

```
"body": "@union(outputs('compose1'), body('Get_HTTP_Info'))"
```

Comment: What if the property is already present in the object and I want to overwrite it with a new value ?